# How to cite algorithms?

Tags: citing, algorithms

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{latexsym}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}
\usepackage[linkbordercolor={0 0 1}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup{labelsep=none}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}

\RestyleAlgo{boxruled}
\LinesNumbered

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,fancyhdr,url}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tabularx,environ,amsmath,amssymb}
   \begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \textbf{Input} : An a $K^t$, prime $R$, 
     integer $t$ and data s above\;
    \textbf{Find} : A swq $G$\;
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    \textbf{begin}\;

    \hspace{0.5cm} $L$\;
    \hspace{0.5cm} repeat\;
    \hspace{1cm} select largest $_G(a)$\;
    \hspace{1cm} $B=B\cup \{a\}$\;
    \hspace{1cm} $L^{'} $\;
   \hspace{1cm} \textbf{for} 
   $U(b)$ from $M$\;
  \hspace{1cm} $M-n$\;
  \hspace{0.5cm} until\;
  \textbf{end}



     \caption{Algorithm \cite{}}
     \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

See the compiled output:

[image]

**Question :** The pseudocode given above is not my algorithm. I have took it from some other paper. So I want to cite that paper in the caption. I want the citation to occur just after Algorithm 1. or is there any other better way?

Comment: Do you want "**Algorithm 1 [1]:** Algorithm"? in the caption? It is easier to get "**Algorithm 1:** Algorithm [1]" as you have now and I would not say that this output is inferior to the other option.

Comment: I want "Algorithm 1 [1]" yes.

Comment: That is going to be tricky since it requires changes to how the caption is typeset. Usually `\caption` accepts two arguments, one optional (say `#1`) for the list of ... and one mandatory (say `#2`) for the actual caption. The caption is then basically typeset as "Algorithm 1: #2". You would need a third argument and would have to typeset stuff as "Algorithm 1 #3: #2" where `#3` is an optional citation. That requires changes to internal commands. (All possible of course, but I'm not sure if it is worth it). ...

Comment: ... Note that for me as a reader I'm more likely to ignore anything before the colon as  a designator ("numbering") for the algorithm and will not look for a citation there. But that is only one data point.